# Preserving this context when passing a callback function via Angular template

Tags: angular, typescript, callback, typeerror

My component defines a method that receive a callback as a parameter

```
  sendDeleteRequest(btn: MatButton, cbk: any) {
    cbk()()
  }

  f() {
    console.log(this.owner)
  }
```

The callback is passed from the component template

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="sendDeleteRequest(deleteCredBtn, f)" color="warn" #deleteCredBtn="matButton">Delete</button>
```

However the `f` function will raise a `ERROR TypeError: this is undefined`.

How can I preserve the context?

What I tried

1. Saving `this` in a `self` variable inside the `f` function to print `self.owner`
2. Returning a lambda function from `f`
3. Using `bind(this)` when invoking `cbk` from `sendDeleteRequest`

None of them have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. I did not know that the `this` context got dropped when passing in a function as an argument from the view template.

You can however pass in a reference to the component instance using `this` directly in the template, which would allow you to do something similar to the below:

```js
  @Component({}) export class MyComp {
    testStr = "Value on componentContext";
    
    sendDeleteRequest(btn: MatButton, cbk: Function, componentContext: MyComp)
    {
      cbk.bind(componentContext)();
    }
    
    test() 
    {
      console.log(this.testStr);
    }

  }
```

```html
<button mat-raised-button (click)="sendDeleteRequest(deleteCredBtn, test, this)" color="warn" #deleteCredBtn="matButton">Delete</button>
```

It feels a bit hacky, but it seems to work as expected.